# Why is IIdentity getting reset / replaced in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, basic-authentication

Using the `[Authorize]` attribute on an ASP.Net Web API method causes a "401 Unauthorized" response.

I have an Http Module that handles the `context.AuthenticateRequest` event in which I examine the Authorization header (`Basic` authorization) of the request, and, if valid, set the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to a new `GenericPrincipal` containing a new `GenericIdentity` based on the info in the Authorization header. I also set the `HttpContext.Current.User` to the same instance of `GenericPrincipal`.

At this point, the `IsAuthenticated` property of the `IIdentity` is true. However, by the time the action method in the controller is invoked, `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` has been set to a `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` containing a `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity` with `IsAuthenticated` = false.

So... somewhere in the pipeline between the point where I set the `CurrentPrincipal` and when it reaches the action method, the `CurrentPrincipal` and the Identity is getting replaced.

Some of the methods of the API access ASP.Net Identity users (for a related website, the API itself does not use ASP.Net Identity for authentication/authorization), so the API project is set up with all the relevant ASP.Net Identity NuGet packages, etc.

I've used the same Http Module in other API projects that DON'T have all the ASP.Net Identity NuGet packages, etc. and it works like a champ.

I suspect that the ASP.Net Identity configuration is causing my `Basic` Authentication `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` to be replaced.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's my code:
**Http Module** - at the end of this method, `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and `HttpContext.Current.User` are correctly set.

```
public class FsApiHttpAuthentication : IHttpModule, IDisposable {
    public void Init( HttpApplication context ) {
        context.AuthenticateRequest += AuthenticateRequests;
        context.EndRequest += TriggerCredentials;
    }

    private static void AuthenticateRequests( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        string authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if ( authHeader != null ) {
            System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeaderVal = System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);
            if ( authHeaderVal.Parameter != null ) {
                byte[] unencoded = Convert.FromBase64String(authHeaderVal.Parameter);
                string userpw = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(unencoded);
                string[] creds = userpw.Split(':');
                CredentialCache.Credential cred = CredentialCache.GetCredential(creds[0], creds[1]);
                if ( cred != null ) {
                    System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity identity = new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity
                    (cred.Username);System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);
                    if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cred.RolesList) ) {
                         System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
                    } else {
                        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(identity, cred.RolesList.Split(','));
                    }

                    HttpContext.Current.User = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Api Controller** - when the `Post` action in this controller is reached, `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and `HttpContext.Current.User` have been set to a `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` containing a `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity` with `IsAuthenticated` = false.

```
public class ConsumerAccountController : ApiController {
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
        get {
            return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
        set {
            _userManager = value;
            }
    }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IHttpActionResult> Post( API.FinancialSamaritan.com.ViewModels.UserCredentials creds ) {
        API.FinancialSamaritan.com.ViewModels.CreateUserResult cccur = null;
        try {
            string username = creds.Username;
            string password = creds.Password;

            var user = new API.FinancialSamaritan.com.Models.ApplicationUser {
                UserName = username,
                Email = username,
                SecurityQuestion = creds.SecurityQuestion,
                SecurityAnswer = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(creds.SecurityAnswer),
                IsPasswordChangeRequired = true,
                EmailConfirmed = true
            };
            IdentityResult userResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
            ...
```

Comment: Show your code, and also make sure that your namespaces are what they should be for any filters. I've been bitten by being in the MVC namespace when I wanted to be in Web.

Comment: Thanks, @Ron-Brogan. I added my code.

Comment: @RonBrogan, you were right!  Indeed, it was using `[Authorize]` attribute from the `MVC` namespace instead of the `System.Web` namespace.  If you want to create an "Answer" with this info, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Authorize]` attribute was deriving from `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`  instead of `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`. I had to fully qualify the namespace of the attribute so that MVC version of `[Authorize]` would be used.  Thanks to @RonBrogan for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Your comment after Ron's said you were getting MVC and wanting Web but your answer here says you were getting Web and wanting Mvc.  Just wondering which it is?  I'm in a tangentially related boat.  I have an AuthorizeAttribute derived from Web and that's been working fine on my Web Api controller for a long time.  I added the Odata libraries to put some odata apis in another directory and suddenly I've got the "CurrentPrincipal got swapped between [Authorize] and method invocation" issue

Comment: The signatures of the AuthorizeAttributes are quite different between Web and MVC; hard to see how one could be in the wrong namespace without retooling, at least with the stuff you get with Odata from Nuget